# Is Logback Really Inside Play?

Tags: playframework, akka, logback, play2-mini

Working on an app using Akka 2 deployed with Play-mini. I pulled logback into the project and it works, but its config gets stomped so it was necessary to do a Joran configuration method and have that called at startup. Then I read that play had moved to logback so I rummaged around to see how to use the logger that's built into Play and figured it out, but as soon as I type:

```
Logger.debug(
```

it only supports:

```
debug(String message, Throwable error)
debug(String message)
```

The whole point of logback is the variable argument stuff so you don't have to dirty up your code with:

```
if (Logger.isDebugEnabled()){
     Logger.debug("my expensive message: " + largeObject.toString());
}
```

So I must be missing something. Docs are not great in this area either.

BTW, [here is a thread](https://github.com/typesafehub/play2-mini/issues/7) about the config getting mussed.

Comment: Perhaps look into using Akka's logging? http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.0.1/scala/logging.html

Comment: Yeah I saw that Viktor. I guess I am still a tad confused about whether Akka or play-mini is in charge of the runtime config. Will try and see if this gets me past this. This will support the logback var arg syntax, no? [Thanks!]

Comment: I read them a lot, Viktor. (More than I would have had to were they better…)

Comment: Please send in feedback on the docs as to how we can improve them, it's nigh impossible to improve without feedback.

Comment: I will, Viktor. As you saw, I am 90% positive on Akka so far. Just a lot of minor things that mar the experience of getting going. My biggest suggestion is better examples. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, I'll open a ticket about that.

Comment: Drop me a link. I'd be happy to do one or two. For instance, would like to see a hello world where the app goes out (asynchronously) to a translation web service and translates the words into another language then puts them back together again.

Comment: I still have not been able to figure out how I can take a REST call in which I send a message to an Actor, that then gets other Actors to divide up work, then pulls the results back together again and returns them. I was able to do this with composable Futures and a single Await call, but if I send a message to an Actor, then drop into an Await with an ask inside, isn't the Actor just going to return nothing? There's no ask example.

Comment: Have you've asked on the Play! user mailing list?

Comment: No because I am using Akka/Play-mini. Should I? I thought this was pretty much an Akka question. I am probably going to get a subscription (Typesafe).

Comment: Did you see http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.0.1/scala/actors.html#Ask__Send-And-Receive-Future ? For more info on how to get the subscription, please have a look here: http://typesafe.com/products/typesafe-subscription

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Play is hard coded to use LogBack, and unless you specify, it takes over your log settings. Very annoying.

Stop Play from butchering logback settings : https://github.com/typesafehub/play2-mini/issues/7